# Does salesforce charge for third party app implementation? Unlimited Edition

Tags: connected-apps, app

I am implmenting apps for salesforce from application provideers like Zapier and CloudPipes.

They have mentioned the pricing details on their pages with the usage and the storage options.

But, I am wondering if Salesforce charges any licensing fees for application implemntations through these third party vendors.

Makes sense?

Let me know your thoughts?

Thank you 
A

Comment: When you buy an App you pay the app vendor. SF does not charge you a fee on top of that to us the app.

Comment: More specifically, the vendor pays licensing fees based on their licensing fees. Salesforce doesn't charge you directly for using their services.

Answer (score 0):

Understand it in two lines:

1. If application vendor is going to charge you, Salesforce will charge those application vendors.
2. If application you are installing require more features than your current org has, you will have to pay Salesforce to upgrade your org.

Point #2 is where you pay to Salesforce.